# Regular expressions \b but with not just alphanumeric characters in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I want the same functionality as `\b` but with other characters.

In C#, I want to have something like

```
string str = "\\b" + Regex.Escape(string) + "\\b");
```

However I have some so `Regex.Escape("@(Something")`
will find it in the string `Typing @(Something to you`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you experience is related to the fact that [`\b` word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) is context dependent, and `\b\(abc\b` will match `(abc` in `x(abc)` but not in `:(abc)` (`\b\(` means there must be a word char before `(`).

To match any string that is not enclosed with word chars use

```
var pattern = $@"(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(string)}(?!\w)";
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5Cw%29%5C%40%5C%28Something%28%3F!%5Cw%29&i=Typing%20%40%28Something%20to%20you).

Here, `(?<!\w)` is a negative lookbehind that will make sure there is no word char immediately to the left of the current location, and `(?!\w)` negative lookahead will make sure there is no word char immediately to the right of the current location.

Other custom "word" boundaries:

- Whitespace word boundary: `var pattern = $@"(?<!\S){Regex.Escape(string)}(?!\S)"; // Match when enclosed with whitespaces`
- Word and symbol boundary (if you do not want to find `c` in `c++`): `var pattern = $@"(?<![\w\p{S}]){Regex.Escape(string)}(?![\w\p{S}])";`

Comment: This seems like it along the right lines, however, if you change my above string from: Typing @(Something to you.  to Typing @(Something@ to you, it still finds it which I don't want

Comment: Then use [*whitespace* boundaries](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29%5c%40%5c%28Something%28%3f!%5cS%29&i=Typing+%40%28Something+to+you%0d%0aTyping+%40%28Something%40+to+you).

Comment: Ahh thanks don't know why I didn't figure that part out

Answer (score 0):

For this you'd need a conditional word boundary at each end.
It just guards the string begin and end, if it's a word, it must be at
a word boundary.

If it's not a word, the default is nothing, as it should be.

```
 (?(?= \w )
      \b 
 )
 (?: @\(Something )
 (?(?<= \w )
      \b 
 )
```

So, it ends up looking like

```
string str = "(?(?=\\w)\\b)" + Regex.Escape(string) + "(?(?<=\\w)\\b)";
```

[Regexstorm.net demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%28%3f%3d%5cw%29%5cb%29%28%3f%3a%40%5c%28Something%29%28%3f%28%3f%3c%3d%5cw%29%5cb%29&i=Typing+%40%28Something+to+you%0d%0aTyping+abc%40%28Something+to+you%0d%0aTyping+%40%28SomethingBig+to+you%0d%0aTyping+%3d%40%28Something+to+you)

This takes the guesswork out of it.